# How to find the 31st root of a large number without using calculator or logarithm in 30 seconds?

Tags: contest-math

There is a recent contest in our school.

Let $$
\begin{align}
N=&\ 
330450543498916787547705429904371272937979054655009\\&\ 6798365073248346973369906393714646262613023152668672
\end{align}
$$

I am asked to find the $31$st root of $N$ without using any calculator or logarithm in $30$ seconds.

Since $N$ is a large number, I don't know how to solve this problem without using any calculator or logarithm in $30$ seconds, except for the fact that the $31$st root of $N$ must be even.

How can I find the $31$st root of $N$ without using any calculator or logarithm in $30$ seconds?

Is there any way to calculate the $31$st root of a large number without using any calculator or logarithm in $30$ seconds?

Comment: This isn't a full answer but one observation I made is that the last digit of $n^{31}$ is the last digit of $n^3.$ Which means that the cube root of $N$ (if it's an integer) must end with $8.$

Comment: 30 seconds. At this point you are eight minutes too late

Comment: @WillJagy, who is? Me or OP?

Comment: Since there is a 30-second time limit, is this a problem from a programming contest? Or are you only allowed 30 seconds to evaluate the 31st root by hand?

Comment: @aqualubix  the OP

Comment: @WillJagy, alright, thanks. I thought you were talking to me haha.

Comment: log(the number)/31~4. it ending in 8, you only have 9899/5, ~1980 to check. i imagine it taking about 30 seconds to count the digits though. lol. in for answers

Comment: WA returns $N=2028^{31},$ btw.

Comment: "Since $N$ is a large number, I don't know how to solve this problem " would you know how to solve it if $N$ was (a lot) smaller?

Comment: was someone able to solve it in your school? @Smart231

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This approach is computable without a calculator, and arguably could be implemented in 30 seconds by someone (not me) really quick at arithmetic if they knew it beforehand.

Let the answer be $a$.

1. Show that $ 2000 < a$ by bounding -> Count number of digits, approximate $2^{31}  = 2 \times (2^{10})^3 \approx 2\times (10^3)^3 $. This shows that $a$ is "very close" to 2000.

   - If desired, show that $a < 2300$ for rigor. Less important if we just need to be confident enough to give a numerical answer.
2. Show that $ a \equiv 48 \pmod {330}$ via:

- $a \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$  -> Immediate from last digit
- $a \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$   -> Rule of 3, have to sum digits.
- $ a \equiv 3 \pmod{5}$  -> Immediate from last digit. $ 2 \equiv a^{31} \equiv a^{-1} \pmod{5}$.
- $ a \equiv 4 \pmod{11}$  -> Rule of 11, have to sum and subtract digits. $ 4 \equiv a^{31} \equiv a \pmod{11}$.

3. Hence conclude that $ a = 2028$.

Note: We could use the Rule of 7 "Double and subtract" in place of the Rule of 11.

---

Original approach:

Let the answer be $a$.

1. Since $a$ has 103 digits, so $ a < 10000$.

   - In fact we can show that $ a \approx 2000  $ (and ideally bound it under 2500). There's a subsequent modification that uses this.
2. Let's consider primes $p$ such that $ a^{31} \equiv a \pmod{p}$.

   - If $ p \mid a$, then $ p \mid S$.
   - If $ p \not \mid a$, then we have $ a^{30} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.
   - Hence, we focus our attention on $p = 2, 3, 7, 11, 31$, to help us determine $a$.
3. Doing the divisibility calculations

   - $ a \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$,
   - $a \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$,
   - $a \equiv 5 \pmod{7}$,
   - $a \equiv 4 \pmod{11}$,
   - $a \equiv 13 \pmod{31} $.
4. Hence, $ a \equiv 2028 \pmod{14322}$.

   - Since we know $a \approx 2000$, we could avoid calculating mod 31, and still get $ a \equiv 180 \pmod{462}$ to conclude that $a = 2028$.

---

Answer (score 10):

The number $N$ has $103$ digits in decimal, so its $31$th root must be a $4$-digit number (if it is an integer at all).  The unit digit is $8$ of the result by modulo arithmetic.  Contestants with programming experience may be familiar with the number
$$
    2^{31} = 2\,147\,483\,648,
$$
so $2000^{31} \approx 2.1 \times 10^{102}$, which is smaller than the desired number $N \approx 3.3 \times 10^{102}$ by about $1.2 \times 10^{102}$.  Let the result be $2000 + n$ for some $n \ll 2000$ with unit digit $8$.  Using the [binomial approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_approximation)
$$
    (2000 + n)^{31} \approx 2000^{31} + 31 \cdot 2000^{30} n
$$
for $n \ll 2000$, we have
$$
n \approx \frac{1.2 \times 10^{102}}{31 \cdot 2000^{30}}
\lesssim 0.04 \times 10^{102 - (90 + 9)} = 40
$$
using the result
$$ 2^{30} = 1\,073\,741\,824 \gtrsim 10^9, $$
where the inequality holds by ... *quite a bit*.  This result follows from the value of $2^{31}$, which we assumed familiarity with.  So $n \lesssim 40$ by *quite a bit*, and since the unit digit of $n$ is $8$, it seems that $28$ is a plausible guess.  Indeed, it turns out that $N = 2028^{31}$.

Unfortunately, I cannot think of a feasible solution that only takes 30 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

This comes as an obvious answer, but if the question had appeared on a programming contest, brute force with Python allows well under $30$ seconds:

```
N = 3304505434989167875477054299043712729379790546550096798365073248346973369906393714646262613023152668672
n = 1
while n ** 31 != N:
    n += 1
print(n) # 2028
```

Completes in about $1$ millisecond on my machine.

As L. F.'s answer points out, checking only $4$-digit numbers starting with $1000$ reduces the time further.

And even faster by just computing the result directly:

```
print(N ** (1/31)) # 2027.9999999999995
```

if a little floating-point inaccuracy is permitted.

Of course, let's not forget that all the tricks have been implemented for us already in a language like Python. Doing so in a low-level language such as C (in which there are integer limits) would be a different story.

Comment: "without using any calculator". :-/

Comment: Ah, missed that. Thank you for pointing it out!